# How to get data to an MVC view from Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, global-asax, viewdata

I have an MVC2 web app in which I've just implemented some session timeout code. In `Global.asax`, I added a `Session_End` handler that checks if a record is open for edit and, if so, issues a Web Service call to an external system to roll back the record in the repository, so it's not locked in an 'open for edit' state. The record is still displayed in the user's browser, because we can't push a message to the browser to close the record.

When the user next interacts with the (now timed-out) page, e.g. to refresh, cancel, save or submit it, the web app sees the user is not logged in (the session expired, so the login went with it), and redirects to the login page.

On the login page, I want to display a message explaining why the user got redirected, something like: "Your session timed out; please log in again. If you had a record open, it was rolled back to its prior status."

**Question:** from `Global.asax`, where can I store the message so the login controller or view can find it when we redirect? I can't seem to get a reference to `ViewData` in `Global.asax`. When I reference it like:

```
 System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<My...LoginViewModel>.ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "Your session timed out..."
```

I get an error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<My...LoginViewModel>.ViewData.get'
```

Is what I'm attempting possible, and I just don't know the right way to reference `ViewData`, or is `ViewData` inaccessible to `Global.asax`? In that case, what's my best option for setting a message from `Global.asax` to be displayed in a view?

Comment: Why does it need to be in Global.asax?

Comment: I don't think your solution is possible. How would you know that a message is for a specific user? As they don't have a valid session, aren't they being redirected to the login page by the FormsAuthentication?

Comment: @SLaks, AFAIK the Session_End handler needs to be in Global.asax because it the event is fired by a separate worker process than my main application's process, and so I can't catch it in my app classes. Am I mistaken?

Comment: `Session_End` fires at an arbitrary time, not during an HTTP request.  There is no view or ViewData to use.

Comment: @Dallas, they're not redirected via Forms Auth; instead, my controllers check for a user in the session, and if not found, redirect to the login page. When my controllers open records for edit, they put the record ID in the session; when the session ends, we issue the rollback message and pass the record ID, so we know which record to roll back. But you're right -- much later, when I redirect to login, the session is long gone, so how would I know which user needs to message. Hm, perhaps I need abandon this feature.

Comment: @SLaks, thx, I suspected the ViewData goes with the HTTP request. Perhaps I can do this on the client side -- write a cookie when I open a record for edit, and delete the cookie when the user closes the record. On the login page, if the cookie is found, it means the record didn't close properly, and I can display a message then -- and it would only be seen by the user whose session timed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Val - First, you shouldn't be doing authentication that way. You should be using the pipeline and FormsAuthentication or similar. This can create security holes that can be exploited by attackers or malware bots. Second, there's no guarantee that Session_End will fire, so records can be locked indefinitely. For instance, if the worker process is recycled, no Session_End will ever get called, so you cannot rely on this mechanism to unlock resources.

I suggest you rethink your design to not lock records for edit in this manner, and do not rely on session_end for anything of critical importance.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. We do indeed have a Forms Auth loginUrl, but we also check in the controller for the user, so that always takes precedence; so far, I haven't seen the pipeline do the redirect. Your point about Session_End being unreliable is well taken. This isn't meant to be a bulletproof feature, but will cut down problems with record locking when users leave records open for edit overnight. Changing our record-locking semantics may be an option for our MVC3(4?) rewrite next year, but not at the moment.

Comment: @Val - Forms Auth will take precedence over anything you do in the page, since the code in the page will never execute if the FormsAuth cookie expires.  If you're manually redirecting users, then just add a querystring that indicates it was from a session timeout.  That is, in your page where you do the redirect (i assume you're checking for a valid session, and if not redirecting) send a parameter to your login page with a message.

Comment: @MM, not sure if that will work. My page is open, but the session's timed out. I click a link that GETs or POSTs to a controller. The controller checks the session, sees it's invalid, and redirects to login. I don't see how my controller would know what state the record was in -- it would need to know ahead of time that the user opened for edit, in order to pass the correct error message.

Comment: @val - You misunderstand.  You still use the end_session to close the record, but when the user comes back after timeout, whatever mechanism you use to redirect the user should add the message.  I mean, you know to redirect the user, therefore you know the session is no longer valid.